# Insert logo inside navigation menu , I am using bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, navigationbar

I am using bootstrap3. I am facing one issue. I have a navigation menu and I need to insert my logo inside that as shown below.

Insert the logo so that it will stick to the nav bar?

When we scroll the body up , the body should not go beyond NAV bar. At present, its going upside of nav.

[image]

Can any one please tell us the design.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what I had to do a while ago. This is what I did:

In the navbar header replace the main title `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>` with your logo graphics `<a class="logo" href="#"><img src="/img/your-logo.png"></a>`like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="top-banner"></div> <!--this keeps the top distance and also an ideal place for the top banner-->

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="/img/your-logo.png"></a> <!-- your logo comes here -->
        </div>
```

In your header include a custom css after the main bootsrap.css (keep your original bootstrap.css intact to be compatibel with future updates):

```
.top-banner {
height:107px; /* set this to whatever height your logo needs */
}

.logo {
position:absolute;
float:left;
top:-105px; /* again, use this to position your logo, you can also use left and right */
}
```

Then you can go in two directions, either set navbar's margin bottom to the appropriate height:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Or you can also put a subheader div right under your navbar:

```
<div class="subheader">
    <div class="subheader-inner">
        <div class="container"> </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

And add this to your css:

```
.subheader-inner {
    height:40px;
    margin-bottom:20px; /* or whatever values you need */
}
```

This way you can use the subheader to display navigation or other info, depending on your design.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are awesome.. Thank you.. Are you a designer?

Comment: I tested, the image is fine. Regarding my second question "When we scroll the body up , the body should not go beyond NAV bar."?

Comment: Yes, I am. As of your 2nd question, setting the navbar's margin-bottom to a larger value should take care of your problem, you should set a large enough margin to give enough distance between the navbar and the content. Also I recommend you installing Firebug if you are using Firefox, then you can simply right click on the navbar - and choose Inspect Element with Firebug. There you can select divs on the left and modify their CSS values on the right live so you can test how certain settings affect your design. Makes your design process much faster :)

Comment: Chrome also has this feature built in - just use Inspect Element.